# Matrices/Vectors in C++ with the R math standalone library?

Tags: c++, r

All,

I have been playing with the R math standalone library in C++.  I quite like being able to generate random numbers and use distribution functions that I am comfortable with from R.  My question is:  is it possible to use the matrix operations (multiplication, transpose, inverse, Chol, etc) that are available in R in a standalone library?  I don't see them in Rmath.h.

If matrix operations are available to use in standalone C++ code, it seems that the R API becomes the perfect open source computational engine.  Are people using it in this fashion?

Thanks so much for your guidance and suggestions!

Comment: Have you considered [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most, if not all, of the things you mention are provided by LAPACK or BLAS Fortran code that R links to, not something R provides new code for itself.

If you are interested in using C++ with R, look at the [Rcpp package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) by Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois. Dirk has also written the [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) package as an interface to the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) C++ linear algebra library that can do the matrix operations you mention.

Whether this is of use will depend on whether you are wanting to write separate C++ code that is accessed outside R, or interfacing C++ code that you access within R. Rcpp facilitates (greatly) the latter. Take a look at Armadillo directly if it is the former situation.

Comment: I have seen Rcpp.  I'm quite impressed.  What I have in mind right now is just using the R API in standalone C++ code. If later on I decide to move to interfacing R and C++ I will definitely look at Rcpp.

Comment: @TJB, in that case I think you are out of luck as R is reusing standard (in the computational statistics world) Fortran libraries for it's linear algebra. Try the Armadillo C++ library.

Answer (score 3):

I think the original questions starts at the wrong end.  There is no C++ in R, and no C++ API in R itself.

So if you want to access R matrix functions, you have to go through the R API -- which is a C layer and very much *not* C++.

Gavin in his answer (and comments) and Josh are spot-on: You probably want something like Armadillo for high-level matrix algebra.  Armadillo (just like related libraries) eventually goes to BLAS and LAPACK --- as does R. [ Doug Bates usually reminds us that there is one important difference related to pivoted decompositions; this is touched upon in the `fastLm()` implementation and example in RcppArmadillo. ]

Lastly, Rcpp can help with both cases:

- whether you want to extend R by calling C++ code you wrote, where Rcpp makes it easy to pass objects back and forth, or
- whether you want to embed R inside your C++ application using RInside as Rcpp once again provides the glue

The rcpp-devel list is a good place for more in-depth discussions and examples.