# Including R standalone library in a C++ source tree

Tags: c++, r

I am working on a large open source C++ program that uses the R standalone library (libRmath, Ubuntu/Debian package r-mathlib). I want to remove this dependency: I'd like to include the source code from the R standalone library in my source tree, without the entire R source code. Can this be done?

Unfortunately, the R standalone library seems tightly coupled to the rest of the R code. In the standard R source tarball, the same configure script is used for the main package and the standalone library. This configure script doesn't play well on different platforms. I am hoping that the standalone library is available as its own "standalone" source tree.

Related note: I've looked at the Rinside library, particularly via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736795/matrices-vectors-in-c-with-the-r-math-standalone-library). I think the method I am describing would make distribution easier, for 2 reasons: 1) users that already have R installed won't have to reconfigure their installation (and can maintain a different version as their default installation); 2) users without R won't have to install it.

**Update:** fixed a typo - I'd originally referred to Rinside as Rinclude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points for you:

1. *Can this be done?* Of course it can, just copy and paste the code for r-mathlib into your project. The licensing for that library is a very liberal LGPL.  Now, is it a *good idea*? I don't think so.  Shared libraries have upside in that you get bugfixes, easier and shorter build etc/
2. *Seems tightly coupled to the rest of the R code*.  No, that is factually incorrect.  The whole point of `r-mathlib` is that you can depend just on it. I think it may still needs R headers on your system but if you define the MATHLIB_STANDALONE variable.  E.g., on my Ubuntu box I just did `gcc -o /tmp/rmathTest /usr/share/doc/r-mathlib/examples/test.c -lRmath -lm` and the resulting binary depends on `libRmath` alone, not `libR`.
3. *Configure script doesn't play well on other platforms*.  That is a bold statement, don't make it anywhere near Prof Ripley.  R is amazingly portable, and I fear your claim is a little lacking in empirical basics here.

What you are after *can* be done in different ways, and *has* been done in different ways. 
And yes there is ample documentation as well. Start with 'Writing R Extensions' and 'R Admin + Inst' and by all means come back with follow-up questions.

Lastly, in case you change your mind and you do want R inside C++, you may want to consider [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) as well.  That does however create a depedencies on R, Rcpp and RInside itself.